# OnError at observe an Observable on Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, dagger-2

I'm trying to observe a `String` from my `API` but i don't know why it jumps all time to `onError` method when i subscribe to it even though it creates my Retrofit Builder well.

My `NetworkModule`:

```
@Module
class NetworkModule{

    /**
     * Provides the Post service implementation.
     * @param retrofit the Retrofit object used to instantiate the service
     * @return the Post service implementation.
     */
    @Provides
    fun provideUserAuth(): ApiSMS{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiSMS::class.java)
    }
}
```

My `ApiCall`:

```
interface ApiSMS {

    @get:POST("/api/auth/sign_in")
    val getAuthentication: Observable<Credentials>

    @get:GET("/api/status")
    val getStatus: Observable<String>
}
```

My `ViewModel` from where i observe. When i call `getStatus` creates my Retrofit instance but only goes on the `onSubscribe` and then `onError`:

```
//Get Api Status
fun getStatus() {
    apiSMS.getStatus
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(getObserver())
}

private fun getObserver(): Observer<String> {
    return object : Observer<String> {
        override fun onComplete() {
            Log.d("test", "onComplete")
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            Log.d("test", "onSubscribe")
            disposable = d
        }

        override fun onNext(t: String) {
            Log.d("test", "onNext")
            Log.d("test", t)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            Log.d("test", "onError")
        }
    }
}
```

The `onError` stack trace:

```
2019-07-31 09:48:59.911 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to (MY URL PRIVATE) not permitted by network security policy
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:147)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.912 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:186)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:45)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.913 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.914 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.914 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.914 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.914 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2019-07-31 09:48:59.914 12063-12063/es.devinet.eptv W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/10300876

Comment: Thanks I just solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of that error you might wanna check your `BASE_URL` **NOT** to be without `https`

Also make sure to print the error your method is giving. You should be able to call it like this from the `onError` method:

```
override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
           e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the print stack trace info! It hasn't occurred to me. I just upload the stacktrace.

Comment: I posted a new question in my feed :)

Comment: where is it , i don't see it. you might wanna aska another question though. this one is resolved

Comment: Yes is another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287180/how-intomap-binds-exactly-works-with-dagger