# How @IntoMap @Binds exactly works with Dagger?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm using `Dagger` and i want to `@inject` a `Repository` to my `ViewModel` so i create an abstract module where I `Map` the repository class:

My abstract module:

```
@Module
abstract class RepositoryModule{

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(RepositoryStatus::class)
    abstract fun provideRepositoryStatus(repositoryStatus: RepositoryStatus): RepositoryStatus
}
```

My `ViewModel` module where i include the `RespositoryModule`:

```
@Module(includes = [
    RepositoryModule::class
])
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindsMainViewModel(viewModel: MainViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

I don't know how exactly works this, how is supposed that Dagger knows I have a map and i bind it with my `ViewModel`? because i never user the method. And I have a map include in a graph so it can't be used i think unless i call it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Binds` is similar to `@Provides`, only it is used to provide interfaces, abstract classes or in your case classes that are extended. So there is no need there for any configuration, and `@Provides` call would be not necessary.

While the `@IntoMap` is used as a command to `put` your keys into a map where the key is provided by `@ClassKey` or `@ViewModelKey` in your case and the value is provided by `@Binds`.

Please also check the documentation, because my explanation is for your case specific. But that's the basic. From the Daggers Javadoc:

**`@Binds`**

> Annotates abstract methods of a Module that delegate bindings. For
>   example, to bind Random to SecureRandom a module could declare the
>   following: @Binds abstract Random bindRandom(SecureRandom
>   secureRandom); @Binds methods are a drop-in replacement for Provides
>   methods that simply return an injected parameter. Prefer @Binds
>   because the generated implementation is likely to be more efficient.

**`@IntoMap`**

> The method's return type forms the type argument for the value of a
>   Map>, and the combination of the annotated key and the
>   returned value is contributed to the map as a key/value pair. The
>   Map> produced from the accumulation of values will be
>   immutable.

Comment: But a Map isn't like an Observable pattern? When i map a class is supposed it's part of intern graph so then I should have to "observe" this  this class from somewhere right? Like transform this map to a class again

Comment: `Map`s are data structures, not patterns.

Comment: But they are part of an internal graph of Android right? Isn't like a normal object.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with `Map` and i don't understand why i should map my `Repository`.

Comment: `Maps` have nothing to do with android. `Maps` are basic Java language or Kotlin. Of course you can use to store data on `Map`s even when working on Android

Comment: Dagger stores your Repository in a map

Comment: And from where i get this mapped `Repository` ? From the @Inject maybe?

Comment: You don't get the map, you just instruct dagger to put them in a map. After that the right dependenies come from  `@Inject` yes.

Comment: Think of it like this, you give me 5 bank accounts and foreach one the password. I'm dagger, i put your acconts and paswwords in a map. when you request account number 1, i ask for the password, if it is correct I give it to you.

Comment: Ohh perfect! Thank you again!